# How to connect to postgres db on flutter?

Tags: android, postgresql, flutter

I'm trying to connect to a database on flutter, all connection parameters are correct, below is the source code:

```
    import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

    void main() async {
      final conn = PostgreSQLConnection(
        'localhost',
        5432,
        'trackerapp',
        username: 'jax',
        password: '',
      );

      await conn.open();
      print('succes');

      // query 

      await conn.close();
      print('connection close');
    }
```

when run it gives the following error:

```
*E/flutter ( 7000): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 49389
E/flutter ( 7000): #0 _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:694:35)
E/flutter ( 7000): #1 _NativeSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:960:12)
E/flutter ( 7000): #2 _RawSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1843:26)
E/flutter ( 7000): #3 RawSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:21:23)
E/flutter ( 7000): #4 Socket._connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2068:22)
E/flutter ( 7000): #5 Socket.connect (dart:io/socket.dart:747:21)
E/flutter ( 7000): #6 PostgreSQLConnection.open (package:postgres/src/connection.dart:189:32)
E/flutter ( 7000): #7 main (package:app1/main.dart:12:14)
E/flutter ( 7000): #8 _runMain. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:131:23)
E/flutter ( 7000): #9 _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
E/flutter ( 7000): #10 _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:26)
E/flutter ( 7000)*:
```

help with a solution

postgres used: ^2.6.1

Comment: Just to be sure: have you checked with another software that with those credentials you can connect to a Postgres DB located at that IP on that port?

Comment: As you are using `localhost` can we assume you are using Flutter to develop for Windows and/or Linux desktop? If you are developing for Android or iOS, how are you going to have PostgreSQL running on that device?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using pgAdmin to connect to my Azure Cosmos db for Postgres

```
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

void main() async {

  final connection = PostgreSQLConnection(

    '', // HostName
    5432, // Port
    'citus', // Maintenance DB
    username: '', // Username
    password: '', 
    useSSL: true, // Remember to add this line

  );


  await connection.open();


  final result = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM 
  public."tableName"');

  print(result);


  await connection.close();
}
```